# Batch export of multiple mysql databases

Tags: shell, batch-file, ssh, mysql, database-backups

I am trying to make backups of my 15 MySQL databases on my web server. This list of databases will continue to grow with my (hopefully!) increasing client base.

Obviously, I can do a mysql dump with this command:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table -h host -u username -p"password" databasename > filename.sql
```

My question is, is there any way to batch-export MySQL databases (and, likewise, batch import)? Am I forced to do a backup of each database individually?

In fact, I'd like to script this so I can do it every day by just running a .bat file. I found this online (from this website - http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2009/09/7A.Batch-Script-to-Backup-MySQL-Database.cfm):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DOW=%%i
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
for /f %%i in ('echo %date_day:/=-%') do set DATE_DAY=%%i
for /f %%i in ('time /t') do set DATE_TIME=%%i
for /f %%i in ('echo %date_time::=-%') do set DATE_TIME=%%i
rem Killing all files older than a week old...
forfiles /D -8 /M *.zip /C "cmd /c del @fname.zip"
"C:\mysql\bin\mysqldump" -u username -p"password" dbname >C:\mysqlbackup\%DATE_DAY%_%DATE_TIME%_database.sql
wzzip C:\mysqlbackup\%DATE_DAY%_%DATE_TIME%_database.zip C:\mysqlbackup\%DATE_DAY%_%DATE_TIME%_database.sql -mex
```

Do I need to copy/paste this script for each database?

I'm really new to SSH and shell commands so any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You can just iterate over a list of database names and execute the code above (or similar) for each element in that list. You could also retrieve that list by querying for existing databases prior to starting the backup. No reason why you cannot do that in a script. Typically you will execut such a script from an entry to a crontab.

Comment: What system does that mysql server operate under? This is important, since your solution obviously depends on what tools you have available for the task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to add -all-databases to my mysqldump command: `mysqldump -u username -ppassword –all-databases > dump.sql`

Just refined my google search term to "mass export mysql databases" and found this site: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/